# How to set selection on the first option in PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, preferences, preferencescreen

I need to set selection on the first option in `PreferenceScreen`.
My class is inherited from `PreferenceFragment`.
I added my options in `onResume()` method by code:

```
getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(aPreference);
```

When I start my preferences app the selection is not visible, but after first press on DOWN d-pad button it appears on the first option.

How can I set the selection on the first option?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

final CheckBoxPreference checkMasters = (CheckBoxPreference)findPreference("masters");
checkMasters.setChecked(true);

Comment: Thanks, but it is not my case, I have SwitchPreference.